# Can't bind function to mmenu API

Tags: jquery, bind, mmenu

When I try binding functions to existing events from mmenu plugin API, I always encounter the following error in the developer tool at bind function:

> Uncaught TypeError: API.bind is not a function

In my solution, I use

> jQuery mmenu v4.2.0 and
>   jquery-1.12.4

Hereunder is my concerned code in master page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $menu = $("#mm-menu");
    $menu.mmenu({
        // options
    }, {
        // configuration
        offCanvas: {
            pageSelector: "#wrapper"
        }
    });
    var $icon = $("#hamburger-icon");
    var API = $menu.data("mmenu");

    $icon.on("click", function () {
        API.open();
    });
    API.bind('closed', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $icon.removeClass("is-active");
        }, 100);
    });
```

Comment: Solved it myself. Was not very careful when I installed the package which is not the last mmenu version on github.

Answer (score 2):

Use **open:finish** and **close:finish** insted of *opened* and *closed*. You can see all availables events logging *API.getInstance()* under **cbck** Object. Here the code:

```
API.bind( "open:finish", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $icon.addClass( "is-active" );
  }, 50);
});
API.bind( "close:finish", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $icon.removeClass( "is-active" );
  }, 50);
});
```